# visibility binding in knockout is not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I had a span and i bind the span with knockout for visibility it works while page loading.I tried to change the value by a anchor tag click binding.

```
<a href='#'data-bind='click:ViewModel.setVisibility,disable:ViewModel.completeReview '>Show More</a>
<span data-bind="html: ViewModel.getText(Text),visible:ViewModel.completeReview "></span>
```

Then in my view model chage is

```
self.completeReview = ko.observable(false);
self.setVisibility = function () {
    return self.completeReview = true;
};
```

but it's not reflecting in visibility.I had debug in firebug.The method is called.
Any one have any idea?

Comment: You have show not enough code to find out what is wrong. But if your `completeReview` is an observable you need to set it with `self.completeReview(1);`

Comment: i tried what you had quoted.But then i got a error while clicking the link .TypeError: self.completeReview is not a function
[Break On This Error]  
self.completeReview(true);

Comment: you are using `self.completeReview` in your javascript, but using just `complete` in your data bind?

Comment: @ Thewads it's by mistake my apologies. i had updated question.

Comment: @ArunChandranC well you should be able to do the suggestion from above, by saying `self.completeReview = true` you are overwriting the observable to be just a plain boolean.  you could try in your data bind checking `ViewModel.completeReview == true`.  Would it be possible to give a jsfiddle of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set observable like a normal variable. And no need to return anything on the view because observables will automatically notify changes to your UI. Try this :

*Html*

```
<a href='#'data-bind='click: ViewModel.setVisibility,disable:ViewModel.completeReview '>Show More</a>
<span data-bind="visible:ViewModel.completeReview ">
  Click to on Show More to hide or show me.
</span>
```

*JS*

```
function ViewModel()
{
  var self = this;

  self.completeReview = ko.observable(false);

  self.setVisibility = function () {
     self.completeReview(!self.completeReview());
  };
}

var ViewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/onicuf/1/edit)